# len() function not working properly in Python

Tags: python, list, function

I have the following code:

```
class Stat(list):
    def __init__(self, lst = []):
        self.s = list(lst)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Stat({})".format(self.s)

    def add(self, item):
        self.s.append(item)

    def len(self):       
        return len(self.s)

...(more methods, but not necessary)
```

All of the methods work properly but `len()`. No matter the length of the `Stat` object, the returned length is always 0; I don't understand why.

Comment: How are you creating the Stat object and calling the `len` method?

Comment: first add some item in 1st array

Comment: You probably shouldn’t be inheriting from `list`.

Comment: @ skrrgwasme that's where I'm confused. When creating a Stat object it's created as a list, but since I'm inheriting the `list` class I would think the `len` method would work on the Stat object. How else would I get the length of the object?

Comment: @Frank We'd be able to help if you shared the code.

Comment: @Ryan O'Hara in that case how would I get the length of the object?

Comment: When `my_stat = Stat([1,2,3])` Do you call it `my_stat.len()` or `len(my_stat)`?

Comment: If you want to be able to do `len(Stat())`, the special method name is `__len__`. The right way to call the `len` method (as it’s just a method named `len`) on your current class is just `Stat().len()`. But you wouldn’t need to inherit from `list` to do either of these. Pick one of wrapping `list` (having `self.s`) or inheriting from it.

Comment: @ByteCommander calling it as `len(my_stat)`

Comment: On the note of not inheriting from list, further reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688966/let-a-class-behave-like-its-a-list-in-python/36690145)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it will return 0 always when you are using it like this:

```
x = Stat([1,3,4,5])
print len(x)
```

if you want to override len function use this code:

```
def __len__(self):       
    return len(self.s)
```

Comment: This solved it! Don't know why I didn't try this... Thanks!

Comment: @Frank I think you inherited from `list` in order to be able to do `len(myobj)`. Seriously consider not inheriting from `list` now that you know that  `def __len__(self)` is the key to be able to do `len(myobj)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = Stat([1, 2])
s.add(1)
s.add(2)
print s.len()
```

I have run your code, the result is correct in my environment.

Comment: When calling the length method it should be called as `len(object)`

Comment: @Frank You have to override `__len__` then

Answer (score 0):

Override the magic method `__len__(self)` to control the output of a call to `len(my_stat_object)`:

```
class Stat(list):
    def __init__(self, lst = []):
        self.s = list(lst)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Stat({})".format(self.s)

    def add(self, item):
        self.s.append(item)

    def __len__(self):       
        return len(self.s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to run is `len(stat)` and not `stat.len()`, your function `len` should be named `__len__` instead. Here's the docs: [object.**len**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__)

```
stat = Stat([1, 2])
len(s) # 0 if len, 2 if __len__
```

As a side note, you might want to replace `lst=[]` in your `init` definition, as it can cause some weird looking behaviours. Read about it here: [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)