# Redefine `False` in Python2? How to assign a function call to a variable name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean

There isn't any reason in particular that I wish to do this, I just wanted to see `False` be `True` every once in a while.

```
import random
def dice():
    return random.randint(1,3)==2 
False = dice()
```

This will not give me what I want--I imagine False being initialized to some value as `dice()` is called, and thus remaining as that value thereon. How can I make it so that each time I check the value of False, it is as if I have called `dice()`?

If anyone has a better way to phrase this please feel free to provide an edit. Thanks.

Comment: In Python 3, you can't.

Comment: My apologies, I should have specified I'm using p2. Allow me to make an edit.

Comment: Actually, it would have been easier to get something like what you want in Python 3, since you could use a metaclass with a weird `__prepare__` to screw with variable lookup in a class body. (It'd only apply inside the class body, though.)

Comment: Although now that I think about it, you can't reassign the name `False` in Python 3, so that part gets harder.

Comment: Oh, you want everytime you use a variable name like `x` for it to return the result of some function *each time it is evaluated*? That would probably be easier to explain without the madness of replacing False.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea ;-).  But note that you're only going to replace the value of `False` in your current module this way ... `False` which come from functions written in _other_ modules won't be affected.  You might be able to overcome that by patching `__builtin__.False`, but I still wouldn't count on it working for _every_ function that returns false (e.g. other builtin functions might be able to circumvent that).

Comment: Your question doesn't really have anything to do with `False`.  You can't do what you describe no matter what the variable is called.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah That is a side effect I suppose :) It would make what I'm trying to do work I think.

Comment: A function call is not an object, you can't bind a function call to a name.

Comment: @mgilson Yeah I'll pass on that one. Just playing around in a single module. Don't wanna screw up all of my code :P

Comment: @Goyo Is there any way of overcoming that?

Comment: @AsheKetchum Sure, just add that feature to the language. Look at properties for something on that line.

Comment: I don't know if I can bring myself to call this a *good* question, but I certainly found it interesting. The fact that it elicited the funky `exec` solution makes it worthwhile somehow.

Comment: Thank you @JohnY, I surely was not expecting this many interesting answers when I asked my question either :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need more control over the name lookup procedure than Python ordinarily gives you. You need to execute the code in a namespace that uses name lookup rules you control, which means you have to use `exec`:

```
import random

class WeirdLocals(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index == 'False':
            return random.choice([True, False])
        return super(WeirdLocals, self).__getitem__(index)

exec '''
print False # Might print True
print False # Might print True
print False # Might print True
''' in globals(), WeirdLocals()
```

Note that functions defined inside an `exec` will ignore the provided locals for name lookup, and even if you try to provide a global dict with a weird `__getitem__` override, they might bypass it anyway.

Comment: consider a `UserDict` when overriding a special method

Comment: @timgeb: Eh, maybe. UserDict is old-style on Python 2, and it doesn't provide a clear specification of when overriding one method will affect others. The details of what overrides affect what other methods even change between Python versions.

Comment: `dict` is mostly consistent about method overrides not affecting others, but in exchange, you get weird corner cases where Python won't respect your overrides or where dict subclasses are treated subtly differently from other mappings. I don't think there's a clear winner, but I prefer `dict`.

Comment: Here's an example (last part of the post): [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688966/let-a-class-behave-like-its-a-list-in-python/36690145#36690145)

Comment: @timgeb: I don't agree with that Fluent Python reference. I consider UserDict and UserList's undocumented, inconsistent approach to override handling to be worse than dict and list's still-undocumented but mostly-consistent approach of methods not being affected by overriding other methods. With a UserDict, will overriding `__getitem__` affect `pop`? It's version-dependent. With a dict, the answer is always no.

Comment: (The "weird corner cases where Python won't respect your overrides" I was talking about are cases like `some_dict.update(some_dict_subclass)`, where `some_dict.update` won't respect the argument's overrides, not cases like how `dict.pop` won't care about an overridden `dict.__getitem__`. I consider it a good thing for `dict.pop` to be independent of overrides of `dict.__getitem__`.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that in either Python 2 or 3.  You can assign a value to `False` in Python 2, but what you can't do is make it so that just reading the value of a plain variable (`False` or anything else) calls a function.

You can do it if the thing you're reading is not a bare-name variable but some kind of expression (like an attribute access).  That is, you can make it so that something like `a.b` evaluates to a different value every time, but not so that just plain `a` evaluates to a different value every time.

Comment: That's unlucky, I was trying to make something like just a plain `a` change values :P

Comment: @AsheKetchum some languages support dropping the parentheses for functions of 0-arity, but I don't think that would be desirable in a highly dynamic language like Python, because it would require a lot of interpreter overhead for it to be aware of something like that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah that seems like a very good point. I suppose that would cause a number of problems. (bigger problems than `False` being `True` occasionally)

Comment: It's not just a matter of interpreter overhead.  If you could use `func` to call a function, how would you refer to the function object without calling it?  Functions are ordinary values in Python, so there needs to be a distinction between calling them and just referring to them.

Comment: @BrenBarn the languages I'm thinking of are generally purely functional. Since there are no side-effects allowed, you can have referential transparency, so a function of arity-0 *is* essentially a value.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Sure, but my point is that's not a matter of "interpreter overhead", it's a matter of more fundamental aspects of language design.

Comment: @BrenBarn For sure. Definitely, you would at the very least have to imposing some syntax to get a function as a value rather than calling it. It's not worth it for *a lot* of reasons, just to not have to write parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate having to use . in your variable name, the @property decorator can give you want you want.

Example:

```
import random

class Foo:
     def __init__(self):
             pass
     @property
     def True(self):
             return random.choice([True,False,True])
```

And then if you do

```
 F=Foo() 
 print(F.True) #will return True 66% of the time and False 33% of
 the time.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with just **False**; if you're calling a function, you need to use the function syntax.  You could do

```
False = dice
...
if my_value == False():
    ... action
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to see if it was possible by making it look like the original `False` variable in terms of syntax

Comment: Nice try, but that's a language-defined constant.  If you want to use the value of *one* call, you can do it the way you posted.  To change that value on each reference is the task of a *function*, not a variable.