# What's the purpose of "class MyDict(dict): pass", how is it different from a regular dictionary?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

What is the use of the `MyDict` class and what's up with the `content` attribute?

```
class MyDict(dict):
       pass

company_settings_dict = instance.as_company_console_settings()
message = MyDict()
notification_type = "CompanyConsoleSettings"
data = {"data": company_settings_dict, "notification_type": "%s" % (notification_type), "is_new": False}
message.content = {"message": "%s" % (json.dumps(data)), "room": instance.company.id}
```

Comment: Probably just a placeholder to add more code to basic dictionary type. All the functionality obviously comes from the base class i.e. `dict`.

Comment: @hspandher and you can set attributes at will on an instance of `MyDict`.

Comment: @timgeb Yes you can, but doing it on a class instance doesn't seems very elegant, does it?

Comment: @hspandher no idea, probably highly depending on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line, you are assigning to `message.content`.

This is not possible with a built in `dict`.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.content = 1
[...]
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'content'
```

In fact, dictionaries don't even have a `__dict__` (obviously).

```
>>> vars(d)
[...]
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

However, your custom type will share no such problems.

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...:    pass
...:
>>> d = MyDict()
>>> d.content = 0
>>> vars(d)
>>> {'content': 0}
```

If you plan to design a more sophisticated subclass of `dict`, inherit from [`collections.UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict). I have lined out some problems with inheriting from `dict` directly in the last part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688966/let-a-class-behave-like-its-a-list-in-python/36690145#36690145) answer.

Comment: Do it is true for every inherited class?

Comment: @AmrishMishra yes, a user written `MyClass(AnotherClass): pass` will add a `__dict__` to instances of `MyClass` (even if `AnotherClass` defines `__slots__`).

Comment: Thank you very much